# How to get rid of first element of store id using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My data-frame consists of StoreId which needs to be changed for a particular type of store:

```
StoreType  StoreId
 A           105
 A           213
 B           401
 B           402
 B           711
 B           910
 B           913
 B           915
```

In this dataframe, just for storeType = B, I want to get rid of all the 4's if the storeId starts with 4,(for example, 401 should change to 01, 402 should change to 02), for any other StoreID with storetype = B, there is no such logic and hence it needs to be hard coded like 711 should change to I0, 910 to 801, 913 to 804, 915 to 814.

How can I write an efficient code using pandas data-frame in python??

Comment: Are the StoreId's always 3 digits?

Comment: why would you want to change the numbers? It seems they are just by factors.

Comment: Simply because the store numbers have changed from what it were in the system!!

Comment: Yes the store Ids are always 3 digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression here, along with `where` to only change columns where a `B` is found in the other series.

---

```
u = df.StoreId.astype(str)
df.assign(StoreId=u.where(df.StoreType.ne('B'), u.str.replace('^4', '')))
```

```
  StoreType StoreId
0         A     105
1         A     213
2         B      01
3         B      02
4         B     711
5         B     910
6         B     913
7         B     915
```

Comment: Is there still a better way to write one line of code which would take care of converting other stores(711, 910,913,915) to (I0, 810,804, 810)

Comment: Is there a rule that dictates that change?

Comment: Unfortunately No!!